# Duplicate elements of array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

How to duplicate elements of an array in Java and add them to a new array in the same order of the original array?

```
// Pass an array of the form {4, 16, 8},
// The returned array should then contain {4, 4, 16, 16, 8, 8}.

public static int[] duplicateElements(final int[] elements){
    int duplicate = 0 ;
    int [] newArray = new int [elements.length*2];
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.length;i++) {
        newArray[i] = elements[i];  
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < newArray.length/2;j++) {
        newArray[newArray.length-j-1] = newArray[j];
        
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < (newArray.length/2) ;i++) {
        duplicate = newArray[i];
        newArray[i+1] = newArray[newArray.length-i-1];
        newArray[newArray.length-i-1] = duplicate;  
    }
    
    return newArray;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int [] newArray = new int []{4, 16, 8};
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(duplicateElements(newArray)));

    }
```

Please explain why the above code is not working.

My output is : `// [4, 4, 16, 16, 4, 4]`

Instead of : `// [4, 4, 16, 16, 8, 8]`

Comment: You don't need three loops. I can give you a suggestion: why don't you use another variable besides ``i`` for inserting the elements in the new array?

Answer (score 1):

You copied the original array into the first half, and in the second half you copied - reversing - the original array again.

Intended:

```
public static int[] duplicateElements(final int[] elements){
    int duplicate = 0 ;
    int [] newArray = new int [elements.length*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        newArray[2*i] = elements[i];  
        newArray[2*i + 1] = elements[i];  
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Or use

```
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; ++i) {
        newArray[i] = elements[i / 2];  
    }
```

Where `/` is the integer division: 2/2 == 1, 3/2 == 1.

Now the class `Arrays` allows this to do more expressive

```
public static int[] duplicateElements(final int[] elements){
    int[] duplicates = new int[elements.length*2];
    Arrays.setAll(duplicates, i -> elements[i / 2]);
    return duplicates;
}
```

The above uses an anonymous function with int parameter i.

Answer (score 0):

["Keep it simple, stupid!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

For this task, you absolutely don't need to have three cycles. One cycle is enough. All you needs is to properly increment resulting array index.

```
public static int[] duplicateElements(final int[] origin) {
        int[] result = new int[origin.length * 2];
        int resultIndex = 0;

        for (int i : origin) {
            result[resultIndex++] = i;
            result[resultIndex++] = i;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

EDIT:
Just for more clarity. At every step along the source array, you need to take two steps according to the resulting array.

```
for (int i : origin) {
    result[resultIndex] = i;
    result[resultIndex + 1] = i;
    resultIndex += 2;
}
```